# UISwipeGesture Not working using custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Here's my GameViewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewLoad];
    .
    .
    .
    _board = [[TwinstonesBoardModel alloc] init];
    [_board setToInitialStateMain];
    TwinstonesStoneView* twinstonesBoard = [[TwinstonesStoneView alloc]
                                      initWithMainFrame:CGRectMake(12, 160, 301.5, 302.5)
                                      andBoard:_board];
    [self.view addSubview:twinstonesBoard];

    TwinstonesStonesView *stoneOne = [[TwinstonesStoneView alloc] init];
    TwinstonesStonesView *one = (TwinstonesStoneView*)stoneOne.stoneUnoView;
    TwinstonesStonesView *stoneTwo = [[TwinstonesStoneView alloc] init];
    TwinstonesStonesView *two = (TwinstonesStoneView*)stoneTwo.stoneDueView;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self
                                         action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [one addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [two addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

Here's the relevant code in my TwinstonesStoneView.m file:

```
@implementation TwinstonesStoneView
{
    NSMutableArray* _array;
    NSMutableArray* _emptyArray;
    CGRect _frame;
    NSUInteger _column;
    NSUInteger _row;
    TwinstonesBoardModel* _board;

    int _i;
}

- (id)initWithMainFrame:(CGRect)frame andBoard:
                                   (TwinstonesBoardModel*)board
{
  if (Self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
  {
    float rowHeight = 49.0;
    float columnWidth = 49.0;
    float barrierHorizontalRowHeight = 12.5;
    float barrierVerticalColumnWidth = 12.5;

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) 
    {
      for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
      {
        TwinstonesStonesView* square = [[TwinstonesStoneView alloc]
             initWithEmptyFrame:CGRectFrame(//spacial equations, not important)
             column:col
             row:row
             board:board];

        BoardCellState state = [board cellStateAtColumn:col andRow:row];

        if (state == BoardCellStateStoneOne) {
            // _stoneUnoView is a public property
            // 'stoneOneCreation' creates a UIImageView of the stone
            _stoneUnoView = [UIImageView stoneOneCreation];
            [self addSubview:square];
            [square addSubview:_stoneUnoView];
            [_array insertObject:_stoneUnoView atIndex:0];
        } else if (state == BoardCellStateStoneTwo) {
            // same idea as above
            _stoneDueView = [UIImageView stoneTwoCreation];
            [self addSubview:square];
            [square addSubview:_stoneDueView];
            [_array insertObject:_stoneDueView atIndex:1];
        } else {
            // based on the 'init' method I write below, I assumed this
            // would return an empty square cell
            [self addSubview:square];
            [_emptyArray insertObject:square atIndex:_i];
            _i++;
        }
      }
    }
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  }
  return self;
}

- (UIView*)stoneUnoView {
    return _stoneUnoView;
}

- (UIView*)stoneDueView {
    return _stoneDueView;
}

- (id)initWithEmptyFrame:(CGRect)frame
                  column:(NSUInteger)column
                     row:(NSUInteger)row
                   board:(TwinstonesBoardModel*)board
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    return self;
}

- (void)swipeLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Swipe Left");
    UIView* view = recognizer.view;
    [self move:CGPointMake(-1, 0) withView:view];
}

- (void)move:(CGPoint)direction withView:view {
    // whatever code I decide to put for stone movement
}

@end
```

I apologize for the (probably) unnecessary length, I've just trying to figure this out for a couple days and have had no luck. Here's the bullet points of what I'm trying to do:

1. setInititalStateMain sets the placements of two stones in a 5x5 grid
2. In GameViewController.m, I'm trying to capture the 'stoneUnoView' and 'stoneDueView' properties (set in the TwinstonesStoneView.m file), give them swipe gestures, and interact with them using the methods provided in TwinstonesStoneView.m.
3. Am I generating too many views? The catch is that everything works in terms of what I'm able to see on my IPhone when I run the program. The stones show up on my screen, but when I try to interact with them, not even the 'NSLog' message shows up in the console.
4. The 'stoneOneCreation' method (and ...two) are UIImageView's, but, as you can see, I store them in a UIView pointer.
5. I also used '[one setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]' (and ...two) but that didn't help either.
6. If I add the gesture recognizer to self.view, everything works (the displays of the stones, gameboard, and other graphics appears, and when I interact with ANY part of the screen, I output the directions to the console......just not stone-specific interaction).

Thank you so very much for putting up with all of this, this will really help if someone knows what's wrong. PS: all file #import's are correct, so that isn't a problem.

I am using XCode 7, Objective-C language, and developing for iOS

```
Anthony
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add different instances of the swipe gesture recogniser to different instances of UIView.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeLeft1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self
                                     action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
swipeLeft1.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeLeft1.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[one addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft1];

 UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeLeft2 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self
                                     action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
swipeLeft2.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeLeft2.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[two addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft2];
```

I assume it is because the gestire recogniser has readonly [*view*](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/) property.

Comment: Still no response unfortunately.  Are there just too many references?  When I map it out, the references seem to be sound.  I imported all the files correctly.   Is there such a thing as subviews being burried beneath subviews?  Is the reason why I can't interact with my custom views because they are somehow burried beneath the foremost "surface" that my fingers are interacting with?

Comment: What do you mean readonly view property?  Is there something that I would have to change?

Comment: I mean what recogniser can be attached only to one view.

Comment: And, in your code, you create _stoneUnoView and _stoneDueView in initWithFrame... method, but in the code, you create instances of TwinstonesStonesView (stoneOne and storeTwo) with init method. I think you have to open debugger and exam one and two to nil value.

Comment: Given the same code that I wrote out in the original post, and then applying what you said in the comment (two separate instances), the response (particularly the NSLog in the action method) is not outputted to the console from interaction with the views on my iPhone.

Comment: I created instances of TwinstonesStonesView (stoneOne and stoneTwo) in order to access the properties _stoneUnoView and _stoneDueView.......otherwise I wouldn't have done that.  Unless there is another way to access those properties?  They are both public in the TwinstonesStoneView.h file (_stoneUnoView and _stoneDueView that is).

Comment: You use properties of TwinstonesStoneView thar you create with init method (not with  initWithMainFrame:.. ), and  you does not add these instances to a parent view. Also you use stoneUnoView and stoneDueView properties (from the instances that you create with init method) to get views for the recognisers, but _stoneUnoView and _stoneDueView are created in initWithMainFrame:.. and I think in your code them are nil.

Comment: That's a really great point, I think that's the problem.  What should I do to fix it?  My logic for thinking about all of this was 1) Create instances in the initWithMainFrame  2) After initialization, capture those instances with references to the TwinstonesStoneView.m file  3) Use those captured instances to setup the gestures  4) Then use the swipe methods back inside the TwinstonesStoneView.m file

Comment: And don't forget to add stone view to the screen (to some parent view). Some time ago I've created small project to solve strange problem with implicit animation. There I use a pan gesture recogniser instance, but it is not matter for example how to manage UIGestureRecognizer. You can find it here https://github.com/K-Be/ViewMovingTest/ , see to ViewController.m file.

Comment: Wow! It actually works now!  First off, I decided to create my stone views in the GameViewController.m file, then pass them in as UIViews for my initWithMainFrame: function.  then moved my swipe methods back to the GameViewController.m file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi may be user interaction is disabled for that views , gestures working only for the views which have the userInteractionEnable = YES.